# How to increase the compatibility of my React Native Application?

Tags: android, react-native

Currently I have been facing a version issue, when recently launching two applications, one is like: "Minimum OS version 5.0" and another one is like: "Minimum OS version 12.0"

I already checked the MinSDKVersion of both and they present the same situation:

Minimum OS version 12.0:
build.gradle

```
android {
     ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
     compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.myapp12"
         minSdk 31
         targetSdk 31
         versionCode 4
         versionName "4"
     
     splits {
         abi {
             reset()
             enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
             universalApk false // If true, also generate a universal APK
             include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
```

Minimum OS version 5.0:
build.gradle

```
buildscript {
     ext {
         buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
         minSdkVersion = 21
         compileSdkVersion = 31
         targetSdkVersion = 31
         kotlin_version = '1.6.21'

         if (System.properties['os.arch'] =="aarch64") {
             // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
             ndkVersion="24.0.8215888"
         } else {
             // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
             ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
         
     
     repositories {
         Google()
         mavenCentral()
     
     dependencies {
         classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
         classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
         classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
         // in the individual module build.gradle files
```